# Best (most "pythonic") way to temporarily unzip a file

Tags: gzip, python

I need to temporarily create an unzipped version of some files. I've seen people do `zcat somefile.gz > /tmp/somefile` in bash, so I made this simple function in python:

```
from subprocess import check_call
def unzipto(zipfile, tmpfile):
    with open(tmpfile, 'wb') as tf:
        check_call(['zcat', zipfile], stdout=tf)
```

But using zcat and check_call seems hackish to me and I was wondering if there was more "pythonic" way to do this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "temporarily"? What do you need it for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`gzip.open(zipfile).read()` will give you the contents of the file in a single string.

```
with open(tmpfile, "wb") as tmp:
    shutil.copyfileobj(gzip.open(zipfile), tmp)
```

will put the contents in a temporary file.

Comment: Thanks, this looks cleaner and runs faster.

Comment: To add to this, there is a python module to handle creating and removing temporary files and directories (https://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html). It is very helpful for this case.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered using [zlib](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) or [gzip](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) or [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html).

Comment: +1. Using a native library gets you a number of flexible options. For example, you can decompress the data to memory, or get a stream of the decompressed data and never store it anywhere (either approach avoiding the need for a temporary file entirely).

Comment: I try and avoid this kind of thing, but in this case there is no way around creating a temporary file. Thanks for the input.